# Opencv mouse selection doesn't accurate in camshaft algo

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv to build an eye-tracking system, using MAC build-in camera can work well in first-part: mouse select ROI. But when I am using a logitech camera, mouse selection is not accurate anymore. 
Here is mouse call:

```
static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
{
    if( selectObject )
    {
        selection.x = MIN(x, origin.x);
        selection.y = MIN(y, origin.y);
        selection.width = std::abs(x - origin.x);
        selection.height = std::abs(y - origin.y);

        selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);
    }

    switch( event )
    {
        case EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            origin = Point(x,y);
            selection = Rect(x,y,0,0);
            selectObject = true;
            break;
        case EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            selectObject = false;
            if( selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0 )
                trackObject = -1;                   // Set up CAMShift properties in main() loop
            break;
    }
}
```

and callback:

```
  setMouseCallback( "IMG", onMouse, 0 );
```

Using Logitech camera, the point program set is always above my actual clicking point. May I know why is the reason?

Comment: That could happen if the images are too large. You should try to scale down the images, show and get mouse coordinate on the rescaled image, and then scale back the coordinates

Comment: That could be possible. MAC camera is 720p but Logitech C615 is 1080p. I am new to opencv, can you suggest some related functions to solve that problem? THANKS!

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Comment: Okay I see, I find another solution which is to change the resolution of camera using cap.set() and set to 1028,720.